# Correct python code for entering two times together without errors

Tags: python

I am working on a project related to clock arithmetic which involves having the user enter two times, and then the program adds those two times together. The program has been functioning correctly and adding up the two times in the correct format. However, 00:50:30 + 00:09:30 is not working. It is giving me the time "00:00:00" instead of "01:00:00". This is odd to me as all of the other times are functioning correctly together in the program. I would greatly appreciate your help with this, just a small adjustment that would allow "00:50:30+00:09:30" to be added together to get "1:00:00". The code for my program is pasted below. Thank You again for your help. I think that just a small tweak to the program is all that I'll need here. Thanks. Code::

```
    clocktime1 = input('Enter time 1:')
    clocktime2 = input('Enter time 2:')
    split1 = clocktime1.split(':')
    split2 = clocktime2.split(':')
    Hours1 = int(split1[0])
    Minutes1 = int(split1[1])
    Seconds1 = int(split1[2])


    Hours2 = int(split2[0])
    Minutes2 = int(split2[1])
    Seconds2 = int(split2[2])


    TotalSeconds = (Seconds1 + Seconds2)%60
    RemSec = (Seconds1 + Seconds2)//60
    TotalMinutes = (Minutes1 + Minutes2 + RemSec)%60
    RemMin = (Minutes1 + Minutes2)//60
    TotalHours = (Hours1 + Hours2 + RemMin)%24

    TotalHours = str(TotalHours).zfill(2)
    TotalMinutes = str(TotalMinutes).zfill(2)
    TotalSeconds = str(TotalSeconds).zfill(2)



    FinalTime = (TotalHours + ":" + TotalMinutes + ":" + TotalSeconds)
    print(clocktime1,'+',clocktime2,'=', FinalTime)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `RemSec` to `Minutes1 + Minutes2`:

```
RemMin = (Minutes1 + Minutes2 + RemSec) // 60
```

You have `Minutes1 + Minutes2 = 59`, this implies `59 // 60 = 0` if you add `RemSec = 1`, then `RemMin = 1` and that gives you the missing hour.

Comment: Thank You, this change worked out really well! I greatly appreciate your help